# Impact on high frequency radial forces on ball bearings

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, bearings, mechanical-failure

Dear Stackexchange forum,

*Do high frequency radial forces (e.g. 6kHz) do significantly increase wear and reduce the life span of ball bearings?*

I am looking for an expert in ball bearing research especially when it comes to high frequency radial forces.
I am a PhD Student with the focus on electric drives and i have designed a new electric motor with exceptionally low torque ripple.
This does however come with the detremental effect of high frequency radial forces in the range of multiple kHz. The radial force amplitude is roughly 0.4 N/Nm rotational torque.
Right now i am writing a publication about the motor design for a peer reviewed journal and i was wondering if anyone could provide information about NVH of designs with radial forces and vibration and their effects on bearing health in ball bearings. That is usually not part of standard bearing life calculators.

I am very open to talk to you about adding you as an author to my publication if you`d like to contribute a paragraph about ball brearings and high frequency radial forces.  More details could be discussed in an online meeting.

Comment: What are the bearing sizes, types and speeds? What is the application for low torque ripple motors - space? I don't really suspect a problem for conventional double-ball spherical bearings packed in #2 grease. Not if the machine is rated for overhanging loads like chain and belt drives.

Comment: Which isn't to say you couldn't get unlucky with some resonance in the cages or seals.

Comment: I am refering to machines with a shaft diameter of up to 40mm. In that case it's usually standard ball bearings. Low torque ripple is required in high speed applications in the textile industry or in high speed motor spindles for CNC machines. In that case the rotational speed can go up to 25000 rpm.